# Android application get launched on press of any android inbuilt button like Menu , sound

Tags: android, android-intent, soundcloud

I want to create a recorder type application but my need is application get launched on android inbuilt button i have a one idea for this . create service and override menu button in service then click menu button launch main application please tell me is this right way or not . please help me how i can achieve this .

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would not do this, as this would seriously affect the way your phone behaves, i.e. by pressing the menu button a user would expect the menu to pop up and not your application. The same goes for other buttons. And by the way, you can't override the home button.

Comment: yes definitely it will affect device default behavior but don't worry how i can do this please tell me any idea .

Comment: All keyevent is working only when activity or app will be on foreground. otherwise it will be affect to other running applications also.

Comment: that could be a tool for you: http://gizmodo.com/add-a-button-to-any-android-phone-with-this-genius-head-1221431712